# Replacing global wp_query

Tags: plugins, functions, wp-query, pagination

I have a site that uses a custom query to search for posts by country.

The search results come back fine, but the pagination at the bottom reflects the total number of posts in the site, instead of the total number of posts in the search results.

The plug in that manages this uses global $wp_query to determine the number of posts, instead of the custom query. By default, it works like this:

```
function wp_page_numbers($start = "", $end = "")
{
    global $wp_query;
    global $max_page;
    global $paged;
    if ( !$max_page ) { $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages; }
    if ( !$paged ) { $paged = 1; }

    $settings = get_option('wp_page_numbers_array');
    $page_of_page = $settings["page_of_page"];
    $page_of_page_text = $settings["page_of_page_text"];
    $page_of_of = $settings["page_of_of"];

    $next_prev_text = $settings["next_prev_text"];
    $show_start_end_numbers = $settings["show_start_end_numbers"];
    $show_page_numbers = $settings["show_page_numbers"];

    $limit_pages = $settings["limit_pages"];
    $nextpage = $settings["nextpage"];
    $prevpage = $settings["prevpage"];
    $startspace = $settings["startspace"];
    $endspace = $settings["endspace"];

    if( $nextpage == "" ) { $nextpage = "&gt;"; }
    if( $prevpage == "" ) { $prevpage = "&lt;"; }
    if( $startspace == "" ) { $startspace = "..."; }
    if( $endspace == "" ) { $endspace = "..."; }

    if($limit_pages == "") { $limit_pages = "10"; }
    elseif ( $limit_pages == "0" ) { $limit_pages = $max_page; }
```

I tried modifying it to this:

```
if ($gallery_query){ $page_query=$gallery_query; }else {$page_query=$wp_query;}
    global $max_page;
    global $paged;
    if ( !$max_page ) { $max_page = $page_query->max_num_pages; }
    if ( !$paged ) { $paged = 1; }
```

But that returns no pages.

Ideally, I should replace the $wp_query value  with the $gallery_query value, but I don't know how. The obvious `$wp_query = $gallery_query` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

ty

Comment: Search for questions containing the `posts_clauses` filter. There're some examples that will solve your needs (modifying the original query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'd seriously consider opting for another plugin (it hasn't been maintained in [over 2 years](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-page-numbers/)), or making use of WP's built-in `paginate_links`.

But, in the quest to provide a solution, give this a go:

```
function wp_page_numbers_custom( $wp_query, $start = '', $end = '' )
{
    $_backup = array(
        'wp_query' => @ $GLOBALS['wp_query'],
        'max_page' => @ $GLOBALS['max_page'],
           'paged' => @ $GLOBALS['paged'],  
    );

    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $wp_query;
    $GLOBALS['max_page'] = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
       $GLOBALS['paged'] = max( $wp_query->get( 'paged' ), 1 );

    wp_page_numbers( $start, $end );

    foreach ( $_backup as $var => $val )
        $GLOBALS[ $var ] = $val;
}

// Example usage: wp_page_numbers_custom( $gallery_query );
```

Comment: That didn't do it. In a query that only returned four posts, I had still had pagination for 27 pages worth, which is all of the posts on the site. Also, I agree with you about the plug-in, but that's not my call, and to be fair, it works.

Comment: Hold the phone! I didn't implement it correctly the first try. It works like a charm! You are awesome!

Comment: Got a question: While the pagination works, the links to subsequent pages don't seem to. For example: http://www.morepositive.com/category/gallery/?region=US calls 6 pages, which is correct, but clicking on any of the subsequent numbers just takes me back to the same page. Ideas?

Comment: Are you manually querying the items, or relying on the global query?

Comment: It's a manual query. I pass the region variable via the URL, use it to search a separate table that returns an array of countries in that region, and then use that array to build the WP query.

Comment: I think this is verging off-topic from the original problem - I'd suggest posting a new question "Custom query not paginating" or similar, along with your `WP_Query` code.